# Query doesn't seem to handle the paging

Tags: 7, database, paging

I am running a paginated query on a Drupal 7 site and the page seems to be working correctly (page 1 is the url with a # at the end, page 2 appends ?page=1, page 3 appends ?page=2, etc.).

However, the query itself seems to always load the results for page 1. Does anyone see something wrong with what I have below?

```
    $data = array();
    $query = db_select("my_table", "t")
        ->fields('t')
        ->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->limit(5);
    $result = $query->execute();
    $pager = theme('pager');
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return theme('my_template', compact('data', 'pager'));
```

Comment: Yes. Theming the pager is only a part of this. In the query, you have to use a pager queryExtender to actually listen to the URL parameters. "Drupal 7 pager query" Google results have several good posts about it (I'm on mobile and couldn't link it myself).